# Nested x-labels in ggplot: more than 2 while avoiding re-ordering

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create 4 levels of x-axis labels in a plot. Most examples I find use only 2, so not sure if what I want to do is possible.

Data:

```
data<-data.frame(treatment = c('Control', 'Trap', 'Control', 'Trap','Control', 'Trap','Control', 'Trap', 'Control', 'Trap'),
             n = c('(n=45)', '(n=59)', '(n=39)', '(n=111)','(n=65)', '(n=112)','(n=140)', '(n=35)', '(n=153)', '(n=71)'),
             area = c('here', 'here', 'here', 'here', 'there', 'there', 'here', 'here', 'there', 'there'),
             year = c('2015', '2015','2016', '2016','2016', '2016','2017', '2017','2017', '2017'),
             transposed = c('black', 'black', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'orange', 'red', 'blue', 'orange', 'green'),
             estimate = c(0.9623486,0.964039,0.9471145,0.9487335,0.8527007,0.9639663,0.9530781,0.9492815,0.9318947,0.9654943), 
             se = c(0.008084,0.007722,0.0077928,0.0052604,0.0121859,0.0065871,0.0056207,0.0059268,0.0130123,0.0055851))
```

I've tried different things w/ facet_wrap and annotate resulting in various errors (like points being stacked on top of each other). Least worst current plot (data and labels mixed up):

```
library(ggplot2)
# wrong labels and misorders data points 
 ggplot(data, aes(n, estimate^34)) + 
   geom_point () +
   geom_line() +
   geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = (estimate - 2*se)^34, ymax = (estimate + 
                             2*se)^34 )) + 
   labs(x = "how to nest treatment and n within area, within year?", 
        y = "Nest Survival") +
   theme_classic()
```

[image]

I want the data to be plotted in the same order as seen in the data frame.

Desired plot (w/ correct ordering of data):
[image]

I lot of similar questions are marked as duplicate, but I think having so many label "levels" makes this different? Thanks a ton for any guidance.

PS. the "transposed" column in the data frame are the colours I wish each point and CL would be, in that order, but that's probably another can of worms

Comment: are you willing to use facets?

Comment: Yes, but I do want to keep the data on a single plot

Answer (score 3):

This is not what you were asking, but maybe you would consider a different approach. You can use visuals (color, vline) to present data with 4 levels instead of simply adding text to your plot ("A picture is worth a thousand words").

Transform data:

```
# x-axis
# We need numerics for geom_vline    
data$Xname <- with(data, paste0(treatment, "\n", n))
data$Xposition <- 1:nrow(data)
# y-axis
data$Ymin <- with(data, (estimate - 2 * se)^34)
data$Ymax <- with(data, (estimate + 2 * se)^34)
# year labels and positions
dataYear <- aggregate(data$Xposition, list(data$year), mean)
dataYear$y <- max(data$Ymax) + max(data$Ymax) * 0.1
```

Plot data:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(Xposition, estimate^34)) + 
    geom_vline(xintercept = which(diff(as.numeric(data$year)) == 1) + 0.5,
               color = "grey", linetype = 2) +
    geom_text(data = dataYear, aes(x, y, label = Group.1),
              size = 5) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Ymin, ymax = Ymax)) + 
    geom_point(aes(color = area), size = 4) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = data$Xposition, labels = data$Xname) +
    labs(x = NULL,
         y = "Nest Survival") +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 13),
          legend.position = "bottom")
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think Po's answer is great, but using `facet_grid` makes it a little easier and saves a lot of the extra data prep.

```
# borrowing from Po's answer and using library(forcats) to set factor order like we want
data$Xname <- forcats::fct_inorder(with(data, paste0(treatment, "\n", n)))

ggplot(data, aes(Xname, estimate^34, color = area)) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = (estimate - 2*se)^34, ymax = (estimate + 2*se)^34 )) +
    labs(x = NULL,
         y = "Nest Survival") +
    facet_grid(~year, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") +
    theme_classic()
```

[image]